# for which values of m the set $\{m, \cos(2x), \sin^2(x)\}$ is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

for which values of m the set $\{m, \cos(2x), \sin^2(2x)\}$ is linearly dependent

I have the set $F=\{m, \cos(2x), \sin^2(2x)\}$ and it asks me to find for which values of $m$ the set is linearly dependent. I have the following answers

$a) m\in \mathbb{R}$

$b) m=0$

$c) m\in \mathbb{R}-{1,-1}$

$d) m \neq 0$

$e)=$ does not exist because F is always linearly independent

$m\neq 1/2$

Since I want $F$ to be linearly dependent, I can write the element $m$ as a linear combination of the other two, that is

$m=\alpha \cos(2x)+\beta \sin^2(2x)$

But we can see that $\alpha \cos(2x)$ takes values in the interval $\left[-\alpha, \alpha\right]$ and $\beta \sin^2(2x)$ takes values in $\left[0, \beta\right]$. But since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real scalars such that both are not zero, I can say that $m$ will never be zero and therefore the solution would be $m\neq 0$. But I'm a bit confused because the linear dependency tells me that if it can return zero on the condition that the scalars are not all zero. Can you guide me?

Comment: Are you asking about linear independence of a set of functions of $x$ ?

Comment: @kimchilover It's about linear dependence. Because the set must be linearly dependent for a value of $m$. I need to find what value of $m$ makes the set linearly dependent

Comment: Just what does "linearly dependent" mean to you, in the context of this problem?

Comment: $\sin^2(2x)={1\over 2}[1-\cos(4x)]$ The correct answer is b).